# How to set a string variable as image view resource?

Tags: android, string, casting, imageview

I'm passing a string value, which is also the name of an image in the `drawable` folder using `intent.putExtra`. The string is then successfully pulled from the onCreate of the intended class.

But I'm wondering how I can set the passed over string `message` as the  image name when setting the Image Resource of the image view for that activity.

I'm guessing that the message variable needs to be cast or converted before I use it to set as an image resource name.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

This is what I've tried so far in said activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capturedDebriImageView);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //contents of message is "aluminium"
    String message = bundle.getString("message");


    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.message);

   //if I set it as the actual image name it works but not when
   //I set the image resource to the message which contains the string of the 
   //same name.
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aluminium);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(message, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
if(id != 0){
   imageView.setImageResource(id);
}else{
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aluminium);
}
```